# VBA - copy Excel table values without links

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro and one of its functions is to open source workbooks from a list and copy information contained in an Excel table (ListObject) in each of the to a single target workbook.

The source tables have links and formulae in them which is problematic as they break when copied thus:

```
source.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.Copy _
            Destination:=target.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

I could unlink the table before copying it then close, but I hope there is a cleaner solution to move this data than this:

```
Dim source As Workbook
Dim target As Workbook

    source.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Unlink
    source.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.Copy _
            Destination:=target.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    source.Close savechanges:=False
```

Alternatively,

```
source.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.Copy
target.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Copies the values, but loses the table object.

Is there a way of moving this data as a table, sans the links? If possible I'd like to avoid selecting or activating anything as this will be iterated over many source files. I am open to alternative methods (a comment mentioned arrays) as well.

Comment: Have you tried doing the process manually? ie pasting in values instead of links?  If you can then simply record a macro whilst doing exactly that.  Then simply edit the recorded macro to your heart's content.

Comment: Along the lines of what @err1 said, after pasting from source to dest, you can force a recalculation, then copy/Paste Special to paste the values in from the fresh calculation, thus eliminating the links and formulas.

Comment: Recording leads to a code using Range("Table1").Select. This is inefficient for large data sets and I am hoping to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Ok, I found that my noobishness was showing, I can drop the Destination parameter and then PasteSpecial in the next line, but at this point I do not have a table anymore, just the values. I'll amend the question to be about conserving the table if possible

Comment: Recording does produce inefficient code.. but it will give you an idea on what to do. You should than be able to use that in your code. Saying that, I would capture the range in an array.. manipulate the array and then copy it back to destination

Comment: @AEhere You could try using PasteSpecial to end up with values and then converting that new range to a new ListObject. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects.add